# MongoDB save() issue with array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This code is a post request for sending messages between users. It succeeds when the message is not part of an existing message string (ie: `typeof existingMessageIndex === 'undefined'`). The `docs.save()` results in the error (`"error saving outgoing message"` when `existingMessageIndex` is not undefined.

It appears that mongo doesn't like that I'm trying to save an array of objects as one item in the existing array field.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

```
.post(function(req,res,next){
    var messageStringTitle = req.body.originatingTitle !== ''?req.body.originatingTitle:req.body.messageTitle;

    var newMessage = {
        senderDisplay: req.user.displayname,
        senderUser: req.user.username,
        senderImage: req.user.profileimg,
        originatingTitle: messageStringTitle,
        title: req.body.messageTitle,
        content: req.body.messageContent
    };
    var messageSender = function(docs){
        var tempMessageArray = docs.messagein;

        for(var i = 0; i<tempMessageArray.length; i++){
            console.log("Loop has executed: " + i);
            if(tempMessageArray[i][0]){
                if(tempMessageArray[i][0].originatingTitle===messageStringTitle && tempMessageArray[i][0].senderUser===req.user.username || tempMessageArray[i][0].senderUser===req.body.messageUser){
                    var existingMessageIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }

        console.log("===================" + existingMessageIndex);
        if(typeof existingMessageIndex === 'undefined'){
            tempMessageArray.unshift([newMessage]);
            docs.messagein = tempMessageArray;
        }else{
            docs.messagein[existingMessageIndex].unshift(newMessage);
        }
        return docs;
    };


    //Update sending user
    User.findOne({username: req.user.username}, function(e, docs){
        messageSender(docs);
        console.log(docs);   //Logs exactly what I want to be saved, however saving fails
        docs.save(function(e){
            console.log("Error saving outgoing message");
        })
    });


    //Update receiving user
    User.findOne({username: req.body.messageUser}, function(e, docs){
        messageSender(docs);
        console.log(docs);
        docs.save(function(e){
            if(e){
                console.log("Error sending message within post ('/messages')");
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Need to use `db.collection.markModified()` because the schema 'messagein' was changed to type mixed when it became an array of arrays of objects.

```
 //Update sending user
    User.findOne({username: req.user.username}, function(e, docs){
        messageSender(docs);
        console.log(docs);   //Logs exactly what I want to be saved, however saving fails
        docs.markModified('messagein'); //ADDED
        docs.save(function(e){
            console.log("Error saving outgoing message");
        })
    });


    //Update receiving user
    User.findOne({username: req.body.messageUser}, function(e, docs){
        messageSender(docs);
        console.log(docs);
        docs.markModified('messagein'); //ADDED
        docs.save(function(e){
            if(e){
                console.log("Error sending message within post ('/messages')");
            }
        });
```

Note: The solution worked, however the explanation is just my guess, please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!